# Horizontal scrolling even if all the elements have width: 100%?

Tags: css

Here I uploaded the site:

http://staging.18d959a75b.applications.strobeapp.com/?q=b&place=9&dish=7745

1. Shrink your browser 480px or less.
2. Make any search (you can write 'b').
3. Click one item's title.

You will realize that you can scroll to the right. I don't understand why because all the elements have width: 100%.

CSS:

```
#overlay {
     background: #222 !important;
     display: none;
     opacity: 0.8;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     float:left;
     margin-bottom:-120px;
     z-index: 10000;
}

div#dish-popup-container {
    div#dish-popup {
        width: 100% !important;
        height: auto !important;
        top: 0 !important;
        left: 0 !important;

        div.dish {
            padding: 10px 10px 5px;
            width: 100%;

            div.header {
                span.top-dish-name {
                    display: none;
                    font-size: 14px;
                    font-family: Bitstream Charter, Georgia, Times Romans, serif;
                    margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
                }
                span.place-name {
                    font-size: 16px;
                    font-family: Bitstream Charter, Georgia, Times Romans, serif;
                    margin: 6px 5px 0 0;
                }
                span.top-dish-price {
                    display: none;
                    font-size: 12px;
                    font-family: Bitstream Charter, Georgia, Times Romans, serif;
                    margin: 6px 0 0;
                }
            }
        }

        div.map {
            height: 160px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        div.menu {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }

        div.menu ol {
            height: auto;
        }
    }

    #footer {
        position: relative;
        #counts {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}
```

What could me causing this?

Comment: I think (not sure) it might be the paddings, which are 'added' independently to element's width

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `width: 100%` and left and right `padding` being applied to the same element. This causes the element to overflow by the amount of the padding. That's what is causing the horizontal scroll.

Remove the padding, or set the `width: auto` instead of `width: 100%;`.